# Forward implied vol vs Instantaneous vol

Tags: volatility, forward, heston, stochastic, implied

In the Discrete Stochastic Implied Volatility Model which is from the standard Heston Model, the model shows the evolution of forward implied volatilities with time.

I thought *forward implied volatility for each time step* is not the same as the *instantaneous volatility of each time step*.

Am I right?

For your reference, I attached the paper below.

http://www1.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/legacy/12804/StochasticImpliedVolatility.pdf

Thanks in advance.